# Bash script adding arguments from variable

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on a Bash Script that will add module customization if it detects that the Java version is greater than 10.  I can't seem to get the customizations to be read in properly as a parameter to the java command

```
#!/bin/bash


# Expect format:  java full version "10.0.1+10"
jver="$( java -fullversion 2>&1)"

IFS='.-_^+^"'
read -ra ADDR <<< "$jver"    # jver is read into an array as tokens separated by IFS


#java version < 10
if [ ${ADDR[1]} -lt 10 ]; then
    moduleCustomizations=""
else
    moduleCustomizations=("--illegal-access=warn" "--add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.color=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens java.desktop/sun.font=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens java.desktop/java.beans=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens java.base/java.lang.module=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens java.desktop/javax.accessibility=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.module=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens java.base/java.security.cert=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED")

fi

set -x

java "${moduleCustomizations[@]}"  -Xmx1024m com.test.myClass
```

Which through debug, bash interprets as:

```
java --illegal-access=warn '--add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.color=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens java.desktop/sun.font=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens java.desktop/java.beans=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens java.base/java.lang.module=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens java.desktop/javax.accessibility=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.module=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens java.base/java.security.cert=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED' -Xmx1024m com.test.myClass
```

So I believe the problem is that the single quotes are appearing in all but the first item passed to the java command.  How can I get bash to properly pass the arguments?

EDIT:

Adding another method I've tried keeping $moduleCustomizations as one string:

```
#!/bin/bash


# Expect format:  java full version "10.0.1+10"
jver="$( java -fullversion 2>&1)"

IFS='.-_^+^"'
read -ra ADDR <<< "$jver"    # jver is read into an array as tokens separated by IFS


#java version < 10
if [ ${ADDR[1]} -lt 10 ]; then
    moduleCustomizations=""
else
    moduleCustomizations="--illegal-access=warn --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.color=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.beans=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.module=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/javax.accessibility=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.module=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.security.cert=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED"

fi

set -x

java "${moduleCustomizations}"  -Xmx1024m com.test.myClass
```

But this turns into:

```
 java '--illegal-access=warn --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.color=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.beans=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.module=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/javax.accessibility=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.module=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.security.cert=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED' -Xmx1024m com.test.myClass
```

And bash interprets the argument as one big argument.

EDIT2:

Trying again but this time without quotes around ${moduleCustomizations}.  It seems to remove all dashes:

```
java '' '' illegal 'access=warn ' '' add 'opens java' desktop/java awt color=ALL 'UNNAMED ' '' add 'opens java' desktop/sun font=ALL 'UNNAMED ' '' add 'opens java' desktop/java beans=ALL 'UNNAMED ' '' add 'opens java' base/java lang=ALL 'UNNAMED ' '' add 'opens java' base/java lang module=ALL 'UNNAMED ' '' add 'opens java' desktop/javax swing=ALL 'UNNAMED ' '' add 'opens java' desktop/java awt=ALL 'UNNAMED ' '' add 'opens java' desktop/sun awt image=ALL 'UNNAMED ' '' add 'opens java' desktop/javax accessibility=ALL 'UNNAMED ' '' add 'opens java' desktop/sun awt=ALL 'UNNAMED ' '' add 'opens java' base/jdk internal module=ALL 'UNNAMED ' '' add 'opens java' base/java security cert=ALL 'UNNAMED ' '' add 'opens java' base/java security=ALL 'UNNAMED ' '' add 'opens java' base/java net=ALL 'UNNAMED ' '' add 'opens java' base/java lang ref=ALL UNNAMED -Xmx1024m com.test.myClass
```

Comment: Why don't you populate `moduleCustomizations` as a single string like `moduleCustomizations="--illegal-access=warn --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.color=ALL-UNNAMED ...."`?

Comment: I started out trying that way but it seemed to interpret the moduleCustomizations variable as one large argument.  I've modified to add an example of that as well

Comment: Please try single string option but calling java like `java ${moduleCustomizations}  -Xmx1024m com.test.myClass`. Without quotes around `moduleCustomizations`

Comment: Thanks -- just tried that and it seems to act similarly, but just removes the dashes.  Added to question to show what I mean.

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is directly pertinent.

Comment: Re: unquoted expansion removing the dashes, that's because you've got them in `IFS`. Which is *absolutely not* to say that unquoted expansion is a practice you should use; it's probably responsible for more [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) entries than any other single error. Using an array, as that other guy's answer shows, means you can use quoting/escaping/spaces/etc within your optionally-added arguments.

Comment: BTW, if you put `IFS='.-_^+^"' read -ra ADDR <<< "$jver"` all on the same line, the `IFS` change would **only** impact the `read`, and avoid modifying behavior of future commands later in the file.

Comment: (though maybe a regex match for the JVM version would make more sense in the first place? `jvm_major_version_re='java version "([0-9]+)[.]'; if [[ $(java -version) =~ $jvm_major_version_re ]]; then jvm_major_version=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; fi`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're merging together what should be two separate arguments:

```
"--add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.color=ALL-UNNAMED"
```

Don't try to make it harder than it is, because you wouldn't try to run:

```
java "--add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.color=ALL-UNNAMED"
```

Just put whatever you would add after the `java` command directly inside the array without trying to add additional quoting:

```
java --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.color=ALL-UNNAMED
```

becomes:

```
args=( --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.color=ALL-UNNAMED )
java "${args[@]}"
```

In your code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Expect format:  java full version "10.0.1+10"
jver="$( java -fullversion 2>&1)"

# jver is read into an array as tokens separated by IFS
IFS='.-_^+"' read -ra ADDR <<< "$jver"    

#java version < 10
if [[ "${ADDR[1]}" -lt 10 ]]; then
    moduleCustomizations=()
else
    moduleCustomizations=(
       --illegal-access=warn
       --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.color=ALL-UNNAMED
       --add-opens java.desktop/sun.font=ALL-UNNAMED
       --add-opens java.desktop/java.beans=ALL-UNNAMED
       --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
       --add-opens java.base/java.lang.module=ALL-UNNAMED
       --add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED
       --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED
       --add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED
       --add-opens java.desktop/javax.accessibility=ALL-UNNAMED
       --add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED
       --add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.module=ALL-UNNAMED
       --add-opens java.base/java.security.cert=ALL-UNNAMED
       --add-opens java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED
       --add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
       --add-opens java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
    )
fi
set -x
java "${moduleCustomizations[@]}"  -Xmx1024m com.test.myClass
```

---

Also note that any quotes that do or don't appear in `set -x` output are purely disambiguation notation for your benefit. They don't change or decide what's being passed to the command. It's just so that your human eyes can tell the difference between argument arrays like (in Java notation):

```
{"hello", "world"}
{"hello", "world", ""}
{"hello world"}
{"hello world", "", ""}
```

Because if you just appended and printed the words, all these different arrays would read `hello world` and that's not very helpful when debugging.